# Downloading 'Yum groupinstall "development tools"'?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, yum

I've looked all over and build essentials are all I see that was replaced by Development tools. When I type the command I receive "no such command".

What is the alternative to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apt-get build-dep package-i-want-to-build` to get everything you need to build `package` - often the easiest way to get the dev tools is to pick a sufficiently complicated package like pidgin and run this

or

`apt-get install build-essential` to just get a compiler

Comment: It states I have everything I already need. However, when I try to install a few things using for example /autogen.sh or ./configure I had to manually get a few things...took about 20-30 minutes of research before I could find what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu doesn't use yum. You still want to use the apt instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Debian, Ubuntu, Mint, etc. have APT package manager, not YUM. In these OSes you generally need to do following to install basic development tools, like C and C++ compilers, binutils, etc:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```